# New content_xxxxx.xml layout file in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

I just updated Android Studio from 1.3 to 1.4 and there are some new features which I don't quite get.When creating a new `Blank Activity`, two .xml layout files are added. The name of my Activity is `PaymentActivity`, so I get `content_payment.xml` and `activity_payment.xml`. This `content_payment.xml` file contains nothing other than a `RelativeLayout` which has this defined in it:

```
 tools:showIn="@layout/activity_payment">
```

What is this new layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They make for you a layout for this or that type of Activity (Blank Activity, Scrolling Activity etc) which implements this or that functionality AND includes your own content in the form of an included `content_xxx` layout..

Each such layout contains `content_xxx` layout where your own content is supposed to go.

In your case no functionality for that outer layout (because Blank Activity), so that outer layout simply contains your content layout, adding nothing fancy by itself. And so you just put your content into that `content_xxx` layout.

This way you can easy change your blank activity to, say, scrolling one sometime later.

Comment: So they are the same? I can delete the content one, and directly edit the main one? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`activity_main.xml` encompasses `content_main.xml` and provides some extras like FABs (floating action buttons).

This was probably done to separate content from other styling logic, buttons, etc. An annoying change by Google, nevertheless.